# Gmapping is adding extra points to my map that aren't from the laser scan

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running gmapping using the sick lms1xx driver for the lidar scans and wheel encoders for odometry. I'm having a problem with gmapping adding points to the map that are outside of my walls and are not reported by the laser scanner. Please see the image in the link below for details:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-GsWiHCK1neOUkwODZOX2RlRUE/view?usp=sharing

I've tried adjusting almost all of the parameters and I even tried filtering the laser scan message but the points don't exist in the laser scan so there isn't really anything to filter out. Hector mapping doesn't have this problem. Any thoughts on what's going on?

------- Edit: -------------

While hector mapping creates better looking maps without this issue, gmapping creates more accurate maps due to the underlying particle filter. Therefore, I would like to use gmapping over hector.

To highlight the issue even more, here are two maps, one made with hector and one with gmapping. Gmapping is adding quite a few additional points to the map that are not included in the laser scan data.

Hector: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-GsWiHCK1neUU1LMVI0c19vMTQ/view?usp=sharing
Gmapping: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-GsWiHCK1necFo3UmlWRDFVLWc/view?usp=sharing

Manually looking at the laser scan data, I can see that the min range is 0.0m and the max range is 12.17m, neither is close to my 50m laser maximum and both are well below the outlier points on the map which appear to be about 25m away from the robot. I also determined that the 0.0m points are not the problem by filtering those out.

Any further help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204678/gmapping-is-adding-extra-points-to-my-map-that-aren%27t-from-the-laser-scan./) by [Justin Miller](https://answers.ros.org/users/21825/justin-miller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks fairly normal to me. Your laser is returning a max range reading, so gmapping is clearing all the way out. This could be a valid reading because of something like a window, or a spurious reading because of something like a very reflective or nonreflective surface, or an object at a very shallow angle to the beam. Multiple views of the same area may help, but if hector mapping works better for you, then use that.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Justin Miller](https://answers.ros.org/users/21825/justin-miller/) on 2015-03-10**:
Thanks for the comments. I've edited my original post with more information. I don't believe that my laser is receiving a maximum range reading because I can't see it in the raw message, nor is there a point shown in RVIZ for the laser measurement at the gmapping outlier points. Any other thoughts?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-03-10**:
If it's not the laser readings, I'm not sure what could be causing this. Watching the mapping progress in rviz might give some indication.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried adjusting the `~maxUrange` and `~maxRange` parameters, and adjusting their relative values?

From [the documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping):

> `~maxUrange` (float, default: 80.0)
> The maximum usable range of the laser. A beam is cropped to this value.
> `~maxRange` (float)
> The maximum range of the sensor. If regions with no obstacles within the range of the sensor should appear as free space in the map, set maxUrange < maximum range of the real sensor <= maxRange.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Justin Miller](https://answers.ros.org/users/21825/justin-miller/) on 2015-03-11**:
I had tried adjusting those parameters. They can limit the outlier points but don't define them. If I lower my max ranges to a small value like 10, then I get no outliers. If I increase it up to 100, then the points don't extend out to 100 but remain at their normal ~25m mark.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you filtering out the 0.0m measurements? Maybe you or gmapping is setting those points to scan.range_max + 1 as in the [laser scan range filter](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#LaserScanRangeFilter)? Can you see any other conspicuous ranges, such as NaNs, infs, or -infs in the laser scan?

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2015-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Justin Miller](https://answers.ros.org/users/21825/justin-miller/) on 2015-03-11**:
I filtered them through a script where I replace the 0's with something else. I've tried changing them to NaNs and also to something else like 40. What I discovered is that those 0's are not corresponding to the outlier points. I saw the outliers and some additional points out at 40.